# Access crashes when I try to give a table an alias in design view

Tags: ms-access-2007

I am using design-view to make queries  and I want to give a table name an alias, but after I create the alias, Access immediately crashes and shuts down. please advise

thank  you very much 
nathaniel
Access 2007, OS XP

Comment: Can you give some more details? What is the name of the table, what is the alias you're trying to assign? ~ I really don't think these things matter, but when was the last time you did a compact/repair (is that even still an option?) and how much RAM do you have?

Comment: You say Access crashes "after I create the alias" but you don't say what method you user for creating the alias. Are you using the table property sheet, or are you doing it SQL view? @drachenstein is correct that a compact is exactly what you should try first, as crashes like that are often due to invalid query compilation, which is recalculated after a compact.

Comment: I am naming the table properties in design view. I am using SQLbase  tables.  thank you for any insight

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same issue.  I right click the table name in design view of a query, then change the Alias property (usually because I'm referencing the same table twice). I click back on the main body of the query or try and take another action, and Access completely crashes.

I have found several things which help.
First - work on a local copy of the database, *especially* if I'm working in a SQL statement behind a form or report.  Takes network interruptions out of the issue.
Second - if I can figure out the SQL without working in design view, alias my table by directly modifying the SQL instead of working in query design view.
Third - if I must alias the table in query design view (which is usually me), click save *immediately* after changing the alias in the Property Sheet of the table, before doing anything else, while my cursor is still in the Alias property (Do Not Pass Go, Do Not Collect $200).

Hope this helps.

Comment: What's your back-end database? The same as the original questioner? I've never experienced this at all, but I've only used Jet/ACE, SQL Server and MySQL as back ends.

Comment: I am putting together a couple Access databases for my company. There, The Powers That Be know nothing about SQL and building a database, so I am the only one working on them. For that reason, currently these databases have no front-end/back-end split, but as of today I can attest that this technique and the one below, work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and discovered that the following worked:

Enter the ALIAS on the property sheet
Click in the SOURCE field
Click on the X to close the Property Sheet properties

Not sure why it works but it did for me.